# java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format Spring Security SAML Extension

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-saml

I have successfully gotten the Spring Security SAML Extension sample application to run.  Now, I'm trying to integrate it into my main application.  Before I tried to integrate with my application, I created a sample application to integrate it with and it works fine.  In my sample application, I used the keystore from downloaded sample application.  Now, I'm trying to use the same keystore and I'm getting the following error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Could not autowire method: public void
>   org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator.setKeyManager(org.springframework.security.saml.key.KeyManager);
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'keyManager' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/spring/securityContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class
>   [org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager]: Constructor
>   threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error
>   initializing keystore     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
>     ... 89 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'keyManager' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/spring/securityContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class
>   [org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager]: Constructor
>   threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error
>   initializing keystore     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:278)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1017)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:553)
>     ... 91 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class
>   [org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager]: Constructor
>   threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error
>   initializing keystore     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:164)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:125)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:270)
>     ... 103 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error
>   initializing keystore     at
>   org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager.initialize(JKSKeyManager.java:121)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager.(JKSKeyManager.java:79)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
>     ... 105 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
>     at
>   sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:650)
>     at
>   sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
>     at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1214)  at
>   org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager.initialize(JKSKeyManager.java:117)
>     ... 111 more

Here is the bean configuration for the JKSKeyManager:

```
<bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
        <constructor-arg value="classpath:security/samlKeystore.jks" />
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="nalle123" />
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="apollo" value="nalle123" />
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="apollo" />
    </bean>
```

Can anyone help me with what's causing this error?

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar issue; I figured Maven was filtering out my resources and adding this solved the problem:

```
   <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*.jks</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.jks</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
```

Comment: It solved the issue! One oddity is that at first I wanted to put the keystore in `src/main/resources/properties/security/saml`, and Maven resources filtering was breaking the keystore. It began to work when I moved `samlKeystore.jks` to `src/main/resources/security/`. I wonder if the `**/*.jks` filter is fully recursive or only works with first-level folders.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. Maven was copying the binary file incorrectly.

I had to add the following to my maven-resources-plugin:

```
<nonFilteredFileExtensions>
    <nonFilteredFileExtension>jks</nonFilteredFileExtension>
</nonFilteredFileExtensions>
```

You can test this by running the command in your target directory:

```
keytool -list -keystore ~/<your_project_target_directory>/security/samlKeystore.jks
```

When my maven was copying the file incorrectly I was getting:

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
```

Once I added the nonFilteredFileExtension I was immediately prompted for the password.

Answer (score -1):

You can start troubleshooting by replacing the `samlKeystore.jks` directly in the web archive you're deploying, with one directly from the Spring SAML sources. This can help you determine whether the problem is in the keystore, or in your code - most likely it's the keystore.

In case you're using Maven for building of your application, make sure that the key store is placed in the `resources` folder in your build, not in the `java` or `webapp`. Maven tends to corrupt the keystore during building unless it's placed in the `resources` folder.

Comment: It is under the `resources` folder.  I just have it under the same security folder as the sample.  Which Spring SAML sources are you referring to?

Comment: I was referring to this file https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/blob/master/sample/src/main/resources/security/samlKeystore.jks

Comment: I replaced the keystore as you suggested and I'm still getting the error.  We are using Maven, but as I said earlier, it's under the resources folder.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately not without a possibility to reproduce it. It's like shooting in the dark.