# Jetty: Error initializing keystore

Tags: java, jetty, keystore, spring-saml, okta-api

For starters, I have already refereed these questions on stackoverflow and they didn't solve my problem, therefore creating a new one:

[java.io.IOException: Invalid Keystore format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052700/java-io-ioexception-invalid-keystore-format)

[tomcat 7 ssl invalid keystore format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33196674/tomcat-7-ssl-invalid-keystore-format)

**Problem:**

While integrating SAML with my Jetty web app(by following the tutorial at: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/03/16/spring-boot-saml), I get following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing keystore
```

I have tried creating the keystore from multiple versions of JDK but for all files, I get the same error.

Also I am not using maven.

EDIT:

Exception trace:

```
unavailable Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing keystore
FAILED o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@550dbc7a{/api,null,STARTING}: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet-7b2bbc3@bef2d67e==org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet,-1,false org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet-7b2bbc3@bef2d67e==org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet,-1,false
FAILED  
Error Details:
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet-7b2bbc3@bef2d67e==org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet,-1,false
Server exiting.
```

Comment: did you check out this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764806/java-io-ioexception-invalid-keystore-format-spring-security-saml-extension

Comment: Yes I did. It gives the solution as "maven might be filtering out the jks file". I am not using maven as mentioned in my question.

Comment: And does keytool work on this file ? Try C:\Java\jdk_1.7.3\bin>keytool -list keystore.jks

Comment: I get "Illegal option:  keystore.jks"

Comment: Correction: keytool -list -keystore keystore.jks gives correct output. No error

Comment: can you post the complete Exception trace ? The cause of this exception might be interesting to see...

Comment: @AxelPodehl updated exception trace in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after downloading the source and debugging for a while, I found out the problem.

Turns out, this line from source was causing the problem(the link i mentioned in my question uses this code):
[Spring Security with SAML](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml-dsl/blob/7a6731c93260f3b533dc93b7519bece8504fbef5/spring-security-saml-dsl/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/extensions/saml2/config/SAMLConfigurer.java#L415)

I changed the following line:

```
DefaultResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
Resource storeFile = loader.getResource(keyStore.getStoreFilePath());
```

to

```
Resource storeFile = new FileSystemResource(keyStore.getStoreFilePath());
```

and it works perfectly. The only change I did was using `FileSystemResource` instead of `DefaultResourceLoader`

Although, In a different application, no change was needed, I am not sure why it fails to read the same file in 1 application and fails in another. More debugging is required. However, I am sharing the solution, in case someone stumbles upon the same problem.

Comment: `DefaultResourceLoader` resolves class path resources whereas the `FileSystemResourceLoader` resolves plain paths as file system resources.

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/FileSystemResourceLoader.html